# Javascript: hide alert and place a cookie

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert, show-hide, setcookie

This is obviously another "site surprisingly uses cookies" alert.

I meant to make it hide and place a cookie "seen" on button click.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/cookies.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cookiemessage_main">Blah-blah<input type="button" value="oh no" id="cookiemessage_main_button" onclick="notified('seen', '1', 3)"></div>
</body>
```

here's the script:

```
function notified(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;

       var main_note = document.getElementById("cookienote");
       var main_message = document.getElementById("cookiemessage_main");
       var inner_message = document.getElementById("cookiemessage_inner");

          main_note.style.display = 'none';
          main_message.style.display = 'none';
          inner_message.style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

It does place a cookie but doesn't hide any element live. (Please note the page contains only 1 or 2 of the 3 'id's mentioned in JS - it's got main and inner versions, desktop and mobile versions...)

Wazzup guys?

Comment: Please always check your browser console for errors; it's supposed to be `document.getElementById("cookiemessage_main")`

Comment: Thanks... ookay! It works in half of the cases: the third line doesn't. If I simply change the order, the new third line doesn't disappear...

Comment: What do you mean? Which "third line"? Also, hiding an element also hides all its children; do you really need two hide three elements?

Comment: `main_note.style.display = 'none';
          main_message.style.display = 'none';
          inner_message.style.display = 'none';` - it does NOT hide the 3rd one, and if I just change the sequence - it will NOT hide the new 3rd one (a previous one will work fine), it seems to somehow escape after 2

Comment: If `document.getElementById` doesn't find the element based on the text you state, it returns `null` / `undefined`. When that happens and you try to access `.style` of `undefined`, JS will display an error accordingly and simply stop running. Please put the actual code you have in the question, you most likely made a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks, now I see. Only 1 or 2 of the three elements are present on the page. Is there any option to avoid this bug and to make the script perform next modifications after it can't modify some elements? Hide abscent 1, hide abscent 2, finally hide the present 3.

Comment: You can use something like `if (main_note) main_note.style.display = 'none';` Or you can use jQuery: `$('#cookienote').hide();`